# protractor pass browser name to conf.js from command prompt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

my conf.js file

```
    framework: 'jasmine',
        jasmineNodeOpts: {
            onComplete: null,
            isVerbose: false,
            showColors: true,
            includeStackTrace: false,
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 250000
        },
        'autoStartStopServer': true,
     capabilities: {
          'browserName': 'chrome',
           shardTestFiles: true,
           maxInstances: 3
          },
suites: {  
         Script001 : '../specs/SampleScript001.js',
         Script002 : '../specs/SampleScript002.js',
         Script003 : '../specs/SampleScript003.js';       
    },
```

i can pass suit name to conf.js file from command prompt as

```
protractor conf.js --suite Script001 
or
protractor conf.js --suite Script001,Script002
```

is there a way to pass **browserName** and **maxInstances** to conf.js from command prompt?

**FYI.. i had to execute my test scripts in parallel in my local machine**

Comment: I think to test for different browser best way is to have a separate conf file for all browser, so that you will have a clear picture what configuration you have for specific browser.

Comment: Our solution is to use a shell script to export command line options as environment variables. The protractor config can use those environment variables as the shell script launches protractor. It gives us a lot more control and flexibility from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option to read command line arguments along with https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner to have a fully configurable runner.

Example Grunt configuration -

```
 var browser = grunt.option('browser') || 'firefox';
 grunt.initConfig({  
    protractor: {
      options: {
        keepAlive: false
      },
      local: {
        configFile:"conf.js",
        options: {
          keepAlive: true,
          webdriverManagerUpdate: true,
          args: {
            params: {
              baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8001/#/'
            },
            capabilities: {
              'browserName': browser
            },
            verbose:false
          }
       }
    }
 });
```

where the `baseUrl` is your applications starting URL.